# Posting with content type multipart/form-data in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data

I'm creating an API end point to upload files in .net core 2 as follow

```
 [HttpPost("{userId}/files")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddUserFile([FromRoute]string userId)
    {
        var file = Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();

        var myFile = new MyFiles
        {
            FilePath = await UploadFile(file), // save the file and return url
            UserId = userId,
            FileName = Request.Form["fileName"],
            Description = Request.Form["description"]
        };

        // todo save file to database

        return Ok(myFile);
    }
```

I tested this end point using Postman and it works as expected.

when tried to call this end point from an Angular application as follow

```
onAddFile(form: NgForm) {

   const formData: FormData = new FormData();
   formData.append('', this.selectedFile);
   formData.append('fileName', form.value.fileName);
   formData.append('description', form.value.description);
   formData.append('userId', this.userId);

   const headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('accept-language', 'en');
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
   headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

   this.http.post(
     `https://localhost:44339/api/admin/users/${this.userId}/files`,
     formData,
     new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })
   ).subscribe(result => {
     console.log(result);
   });
 }
```

I get the following error

> :44339/api/admin/users/c6d15e43-00b9-4eda-bac8-635f6017fec9/files:1
>   POST
>   https://localhost:44339/api/admin/users/c6d15e43-00b9-4eda-bac8-635f6017fec9/files
>
> edit:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44339/api/admin/users/c6d15e43-00b9-4eda-bac8-635f6017fec9/files.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

[image]

and this is the captured request header from the Angular app

```
:authority:localhost:44339
:method:POST
:path:/api/admin/users/c6d15e43-00b9-4eda-bac8-635f6017fec9/files
:scheme:https
accept:application/json
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6
authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIU.........
content-length:21531
content-type:multipart/form-data;
origin:http://localhost:4200
referer:http://localhost:4200/admin/users/c6d15e43-00b9-4eda-bac8-635f6017fec9/edit
```

and my request payload

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryqB4rbqWsrra0gwhi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="2017-08-22_21-56-02.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryqB4rbqWsrra0gwhi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"

er
------WebKitFormBoundaryqB4rbqWsrra0gwhi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

df
------WebKitFormBoundaryqB4rbqWsrra0gwhi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userId"

c6d15e43-00b9-4eda-bac8-635f6017fec9
------WebKitFormBoundaryqB4rbqWsrra0gwhi--
```

while trying to figure out the issue I noticed that this happens only if the request `content-type` is `multipart/form-data`, which I have to use in this case to be able to upload the file.

what am I missing here, am I doing some thing wrong in angular or I missed a configuration in the server side API?

---

**Edit:**

cors configuration in startup

```
  app.UseCors(builder =>
                builder
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowCredentials()
            );
```

Comment: Can you show me the code. Your server side setHeader ?

Comment: Have you enabled CORS on backend? E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api Show your RESPONSE headers...

Comment: @A.Tim, I edited the question showing my cors configuration

Comment: @Chandru what do you mean by 'server side setHeader' !?

Comment: Once again, please show your RESPONSE headers when your application "works" and when it doesn't work (you said " I noticed that this happens only if the request `content-type` is `multipart/form-data`"). I assume that somehow your backend omit setting proper headers for multipart requests. I'm not familiar with ASP, but same sometimes happens in Spring, when app has multiple request filters.

Comment: you want enable cors on your backend like : res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: *“The response had HTTP status code 500.”* simply indicates a failure on the server side that has halted execution. That’s the actual problem you need to identify the cause of and fix. The fact there’s no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in that 500 error response actually isn’t important, because the server is telling you there’s some fatal error—some server-side failure—that prevents the server from proceeding further at all. (Many or most servers won’t add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to 5xx or 4xx error responses—instead they only add that header to 2xx success responses.)

Comment: @sideshowbarker interesting explanation for the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to overcome this issue finally, the fix is to delete the content type from the header

`headers.delete('Content-Type');`

don't leave it empty this will cause an error

> Incorrect Content-Type: , multipart/form-data; boundary

Comment: Where sis you dete them? At request or on server? I've got the same problem(

Comment: at request- in the client side

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the CORS on backend as suggested by A.Tim. Following is how it is done in Java for a Spring based app.

```
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
            corsRegistry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedHeaders("*").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo in Angular’s http url:

> https://localhost:44339/api/admin/users/${this.userId}/files

It should be (note the port)

> https://localhost:4200/api/admin/users/${this.userId}/files

Or better yet, use a relative url so the host is automatically calculated.

If you're actually runing these 2 apps in localhost make sure the one in port 44339 has CORS configured.

Chrome is throwing this error because you are sending a request to a host in a different port.
Note that only for testing purposes you can temporally disable this security measure locally in Chrome,
if you have Windows press Win+R and then execute:

> chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir

(you must first close all Chrome instances, including Postman)